# Check addressed and mailed to outdated, wrong address

Tags: united-states

Change of address was properly made through post office. Debtor sent payment by check to 2-year old address rather than correct address on invoice. Check has not been received after debtor states it was mailed five weeks ago. Debtor states she will not stop payment OR RE-ISSUE  check. What are my options?

Comment: how much money is involved? This will determine if the cost of stopping payment is worth it, Or the cost of small claims court. Location?

Answer (score 6):

USPS will only forward the mail for a year IIRC.

The debtor should send the checks to the address you provided, and if the invoice clearly stated the address to which the check should be mailed, and she mailed it elsewhere - then she didn't make the payment. If however, the original note specified a different address and you didn't follow the procedure to notify the debtor of the address change, then its your fault and you should bear the costs of cancelling and reissuing the check.

The debtor does have the obligation to pay, so if she still refuses, you should get legal assistance.